# Отправка большого tcp-пакета по сегментам

Tags: c++, tcp

Пишу программу для перехвата tcp-трафика в корпоративной сети, при котором клиенту отправляется обратно tcp-пакет с html-страницей (какая-нибудь информация).

Набросал кривой/черновой вариант функции отправки этого tcp-пакета (обратно клиенту), используя код из стороннего проекта, т.к. не могу найти более лучшего.

```
void sendpkt(struct ip &fromIp,struct ip &toIp,int fromPort,int toPort,uint32_t acknum,uint32_t seqnum,int fReset,int fPsh) {
 std::string dt="данные на 3000 байт";
 char datagram[4096],*data,*pseudogram=NULL;
 memset(datagram,0,sizeof(datagram));

 struct sockaddr_in sin;
 struct iphdr *iph=(struct iphdr *)datagram;
 struct tcphdr *tcph=(struct tcphdr *)(datagram+sizeof(struct iphdr));

 data=(char *)tcph+sizeof(struct tcphdr);

 sin.sin_family=AF_INET;
 sin.sin_port=htons(toPort);
 sin.sin_addr.s_addr=((in_addr *)toIp.addr())->s_addr;

 iph->ihl=5;
 iph->version=4;
 iph->tos=0;
 iph->id=htons(random());
 iph->frag_off=0;
 iph->ttl=250;
 iph->protocol=IPPROTO_TCP;
 iph->check=0;
 iph->saddr=((in_addr *)fromIp.addr())->s_addr;
 iph->daddr=sin.sin_addr.s_addr;
 iph->check=0;

 tcph->source=htons(fromPort);
 tcph->dest=htons(toPort);
 tcph->seq=acknum;
 tcph->doff=5;
 tcph->syn=0;
 tcph->rst=fReset;
 tcph->psh=fPsh;

 if (fReset) {tcph->ack=0; tcph->ack_seq=0; tcph->fin=0;}
 else {tcph->ack=1; tcph->ack_seq=seqnum;}

 tcph->urg=0;
 tcph->window=htons(5840);
 tcph->check=0;
 tcph->urg_ptr=0;

 struct pseudo_header psh;
 psh.source_address=((in_addr *)fromIp.addr())->s_addr;
 psh.dest_address=sin.sin_addr.s_addr;
 psh.placeholder=0;
 psh.protocol=IPPROTO_TCP;

 int buflen=dt.length();
 size_t sendlen=MIN(buflen,1024);
 size_t remlen=buflen;
 const char *curpos=dt.c_str();

 while (remlen>0) {
  memcpy(data,curpos,sendlen);

  iph->tot_len=sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct tcphdr)+sendlen;
  psh.tcp_length=htons(sizeof(struct tcphdr)+sendlen);

  int psize=sizeof(struct pseudo_header)+sizeof(struct tcphdr)+sendlen;
  pseudogram=(char*)calloc(1,psize);
  memcpy(pseudogram,(char*) &psh,sizeof(struct pseudo_header));
  memcpy(pseudogram+sizeof(struct pseudo_header),tcph,sizeof(struct tcphdr)+sendlen);
  tcph->check=csum((unsigned short*)pseudogram,psize);

  if (remlen==sendlen && !fReset) {tcph->fin=1;} else {tcph->fin=0;}

  ssize_t len=sendto(this->s,datagram,iph->tot_len,0,(struct sockaddr *)&sin,sizeof(sin));
  if (len<0) {remlen=0;}

  if (pseudogram) {free(pseudogram);}

  tcph->seq=htonl(ntohl(tcph->seq)+sendlen);
  curpos+=(len-(sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct tcphdr)));
  remlen-=(len-(sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct tcphdr)));
  sendlen=MIN(remlen,1024);
 }
}
```

Клиент получает первый фрагмент и пишет об ошибки чтения данных. По dump трафика вижу все пакеты и в них верные seq. Содержимое в пакетах есть. Не могу понять в чем я ошибся. Может какой-то флаг забыл?

Comment: А как клиент читает пакет? Может, он ошибочно ожидает, что пакет придёт к нему одним махом? (Это популярная ошибка.)

Comment: Клиент обычный браузер. Не нашел бита в tcp где сообщается, что пакет фрагментирован.

Comment: TCP — потоковый протокол, так что его может и не быть.

Comment: Эээ, а в каком смысле клиент — браузер? Браузер принимает HTTP. Или вы имеете в виду не браузер, а JS, бегущий в браузере и читающий что-то из сокета?

Comment: ну пусть так) разницы никакой

Comment: Разница в том, что код на JS может быть и с багами. Давайте принимающий код в вопрос. А вот баг в коде самого браузера я бы исключил.

Comment: @nerik, вам  не надоело один и тот же вопрос создавать и удалять уже 4 раз!? Предыдущий был тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685072/186083

Comment: @Visman нет. В предыдущих 4 раза завалили флудом, пришлось пересоздавать. К тому же в тех 4 разах, были другие вопросы по коду, которые решились

Comment: @VladD в таком случаи, пусть будет браузер. Ну или wget например, который пишет -  Read error at byte 839/2699 (Connection reset by peer). Retrying.

Comment: @nerik: Удалять вопросы нехорошо и эгоистично. Ответы ведь даются не лично вам, а всему сообществу.

Comment: А как вы определили, что seq верные ? Сравните поведение seq в нормальной tcp сессии и в полученной вами

Comment: @Mike это я и сделал. Единственное, что отличается это ack

Comment: так сделайте что бы не отличались

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло(

Comment: @VladD в предыдущих вопросах не было нормальных и адекватных ответов, которые бы решили мою проблему. Только флуд.

Answer (score 1):

Может я, конечно, недостаточно внимателен, но IMHO вы просто checksum (поле `check` в `struct iphdr *iph`) не считаете.

> IPv4 uses the checksum to detect corruption of packet headers. i.e.
>   the source, destination, and other meta-data. The TCP protocol
>   includes an extra checksum that protects the packet "payload" as well
>   as the header. This is in addition to the header-checksum of IP.

*из [The TCP/IP Checksum](https://locklessinc.com/articles/tcp_checksum/)*

Comment: Чексумма пакета пересчитывается командой   tcph->check=csum((unsigned short*)pseudogram,psize); отдельной функцией.

Comment: @nerik, я имею в виду `**iph->check**` (кстати, вы зачем-то *дважды обнуляете* это поле). По поводу его вычисления можете посмотреть [тут](http://www.binarytides.com/raw-udp-sockets-c-linux/). Обратите внимание, сначала оно обнуляется, а затем ему присваивают значание `csum ((unsigned short *) datagram, iph->tot_len)`. Вычисление проводят с буфером, заполненным данными, но полностью обнуленным udp-header (`struct udphdr`)